# How to insert a JSON object with single quotes in Trino VARCHAR column?

Tags: sql, json, trino

I have a JSON object coming in that has single quotes, e.g. `{'key': 'value'}` and I want to store this JSON object in a `varchar` column.

Attempting to insert the JSON object converted to a string throws an error that the line is not closed properly due to the single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSON standard](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) requires names in name-value pairs to be strings which according to the same standard require double quotes:

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, ***wrapped in double quotes***

So according to the standard this is not a valid json (though quite a lot of parsers relax this requirement and allow single quotes to enclose the names, but not the Trino one), so you need to replace single quotes with double ones.

Comment: Thanks! I'll use something else to parse before sending it into Trino.